# my product is already installed / newer version

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

How to detect if my Visual Studio 2010 setup project was already installed? If it was, then how do I get the product's version number?

Comment: Not sure about *your* project - I usually put my app-installed data in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\... (to allow for uninstall through the control panel), and check there. Is this what you're asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get product's version number from registry:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\(your product)\DisplayVersion
```

Comment: If I uninstall my product, then this entry also get's deleted?

Comment: @Bogdan0x400: If *you* put that functionality in the uninstaller (either manually or through generated code), it will.